While mutating shares of a Post, I get "Variable '$postId' got invalid value {'isTrusted': True, '_vts': 1714830156331} ID cannot represent value
Using Vue 3 and Django backend using Graphql, I want to count button click shares.The problem is referring to PostId of Post model in django and graphene-django gives me error: "Variable '$postId' got invalid value {'isTrusted': True, '_vts': 1714830156331} ID cannot represent value. How can I refer to PostId from the Django database?
In SocialMediaButtons.vue:
const toggleShares = (postId) => {  
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(window.open (shareUrl, '_blank'));
  copied.value = true;
  console.log('Post Shared!');
  store.toggleShares(postId);  
  };

And using Pinia state management I have userInteraction:
toggleShares(postId) {
      const postStore = usePostStore();
      const post = postStore.getPostBySlug(postId);
      if (post) {
        const url = window.location.origin + '/post/' + post.slug;
        window.open(url, '_blank');
      }
      this.shares += 1; // Increment shares count
      console.log('Share button clicked. Shares:', this.shares);
      this.updateBackend(postId, 'shares', this.shares);
    },
    async updateBackend(postId, field, value) {
      // Send GraphQL mutation to update backend
      const response = await apolloClient.mutate({
        mutation: gql`
          mutation UpdatePostInteractions($postId: ID!, $likes: Int!, $dislikes: Int!, $shares:Int!) {
            updatePostInteractions(postId: $postId, likes: $likes, dislikes: $dislikes, shares:$shares) {
            post{
              postId
              likes
              dislikes
              shares}
              
            }
          }
        `,
        variables: {
          postId,
          likes: field === 'likes' ? value : this.likes,
          dislikes: field === 'dislikes' ? value : this.dislikes,
          shares: field === 'shares' ? value : this.shares,
        },
      });

